# Using FlashLight in appWidget and crashes when start app camera

Tags: android, service, camera, android-appwidget, flashlight

I have an app widget that is a flashlight.

I turn on and turn off the flash inside a service.
When I turn off the Flash release the camera to be used from other applications.
Now if I have the flash on and open the camera application, the camera app stops because I'm still using the camera in my service.

As I can release the camera automatically or detect when you want to be used from another application?

Note : I am developing for api 16-22

Comment: I have not found how to release the camera automatically when another application wants to access it.
the best way I've found to use the flashlight is to use two implementations , which corresponds to api 22 or above, using the camera with android.hardware.Camera , we have to manage the release of resources for use by other applications.
To api 23 or higher , using android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager cameraManager.setTorchMode( String cameraId , boolean enabled) , you do not need permits for camera and allows other applications to use the camera, turning off automatically the flashlight .